# How to get data from pcap in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pcap, fs, spawn

I want to get data of pcap like frame number, frame time, ip and so on in node.js. However, I couldn't find any module I wanted. So, I tried to use tshark. But the result values was cut. Then, how I get perfect result?

Below are some details I tried.

---

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var fs = require('fs');

var args = [
    '-Tfields',
    '-e', 'frame.number',
    '-e', 'frame.time',
    '-e', 'ip.src',
    '-e', 'ip.dst',
    '-e', 'ip.proto',
    '-e', 'tcp.srcport',
    '-e', 'tcp.dstport',
    '-e', 'udp.srcport',
    '-e', 'udp.srcport',
    '-e', 'udp.dstport',
    '-e', 'ip.len',
    '-E', 'header=y',
    '-r', 'smallFlows.pcap'
];

var cmd = spawn('tshark', args, {
    cwd: 'C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\'
});

cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('done!');
    fs.writeFile('result.txt', data, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
    });
});

cmd.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
});

cmd.on('exit', function(code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
});
```

### result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W15ZH.png)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pcap

Comment: I saw also this package. But my environment is windows 10. And node-gyp rebuild issue was occured, when I installed it. To solve this problem was too difficult and the solution was not applicable...

Comment: FWIW there is also [`cap`](https://github.com/mscdex/cap) that has Windows support.

Comment: '**cap**' has same problems. I think it is connected '**socketwatcher** module'.

Comment: `cap` doesn't use `socketwatcher`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. However, ```cap``` has also problem about ```node-gyp rebuild``` related ```The build tools for Visual Studio 2010```. To solve this problem, I installed build tools. Nonetheless, I have not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assume anything about the size of data chunks passed to `data` event handlers. It could be one byte or it could be the entire output from the child process.

If you're just wanting to write the output to a file, you can just pipe it:

```
var cmd = spawn('tshark', args, {
  cwd: 'C:\\Program Files\\Wireshark\\'
});
cmd.stdout.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('result.txt')).on('finish', function() {
  console.log('File completely written');
});
```

Comment: I solved `cmd.pipe()` -> `cmd.stdout.pipe()`. Thanks, mscdex!